# Cheap USB powered hub to work with the pi without backfeeding

Tags: usb, power, electronics, hub

I am trying to build a 3D printer farm with the pi, and I need a large USB hub. [I found this hub](http://dx.com/p/high-speed-usb2-0-1-1-1-0-10-port-usb-hub-white-42838). But don't know how to evaluate if its any good.

Has anyone tried something like this?
Do you have a 7+ port hub to recommend?

Comment: Check http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals for all known-to-work hubs. If the hub in question has an issues with backfeeding, you could just strip the wire a bit and snip the 5Volt line.

Comment: @Gerben none of those are cheap because they are branded

Comment: You're asking for 2 mutually exclusive things here IMO.

Comment: @Lawrence You are saying there is no cheap USB hub without backfeeding? I [meanwhile ordered this](http://dx.com/p/high-speed-7-port-usb-2-0-hub-with-vertical-stand-black-110-240v-ac-adapter-42750), because someone said it works in the comments.

Comment: ... And I hope @Gerben 's solution of snipping the +5V line would work with the USB hub in my last comment.

Comment: Well, snipping the 5V line will definitely work. That 7port hub is the same as the one that I have, and it backfeeds.

I should rephrase what I said earlier, there's no cheap 7port hub that will not backpower without modification.
All cheap ones don't have proper power regulation to prevent backfeeding.

Comment: I bought 2 of that exact hub from them and have had nothing but trouble. They are now glorified cellphone chargers.

Comment: @ScottGoodgame You mean the one in the question right? Not the one in the comments?

Comment: Update: got the USB hub. I also ordered male and female USB plugs and soldered them all together _except_ for pin 1 (the +5 volts), alternatively you can buy a USB cable and cut the red wire inside. The USB hub works that way. Not sure if I should answer myself with this.

Answer (score 3):

Raspberry Pi boards manufactured in the third quartile of 2012 do not have issues with backfeeding anymore (due to removed fuse), see http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1929 and http://elinux.org/RPi_HardwareHistory#Board_Revision_History.

As previously mentioned you can check http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Powered_USB_Hubs for HUBs, but you should be able to safely power raspberry pi by backfeeding it.

Citing from **penguintutor** post @ http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=17560

> Electrically the only different between the supply from the micro USB and the backfeed supply is that the micro-USB has a 1100mA fuse, whereas the USB ports each have a 140mA fuse. There is a diode preventing the USB power from going into the power out of the USB controller, but not so for the USB supply (which is what makes back feeding possible).

So get yourself some nice USB 1.1/2.0 compatible hub and if it is backfeeding, just roll with it. The only issue I can think of, is that some hubs have dedicated "charging" ports which could actually be only ones designed for >1A load.

Comment: I have both a rev2 and a rev1 PI I can reach. Will test and update you if it works :)

Comment: Got backfeeding from a RAMPS 1.4 board on a rev2 and rev1. It works fine on a PC